# Access violation writting location en código CUDA

Tags: c

Soy nuevo aquí y espero que podáis ayudarme, necesito realizar un programa en C/CUDA para poder finalizar un proyecto de la universidad y estoy bastante desesperado.

Por fin el logrado compilarlo pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código en cuestión es el siguiente (consta de dos funciones que se ejecutan en el orden que las adjunto):

```
#include "cuComplex.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    extern cuDoubleComplex** mainfft(cuDoubleComplex *se, cuDoubleComplex *se2, int fsi, int ltau1, double ret_max, int B);
    int n = 120000;
    double data[120000], data2[120000];
    FILE *f;
    FILE *f2;
    cuDoubleComplex *se, *se2;
    int fsi = 24000000;
    int ltau1 = 1000;
int B = 800;
double ret_max = 0.002;
int lnu, limitenu;
cuDoubleComplex **result;

f = fopen("ref_PRI20.dat", "r");
fread(data, sizeof(double), n, f);
fclose(f);

f2 = fopen("surv_PRI20.dat", "r");
fread(data2, sizeof(double), n, f2);
fclose(f);

se = (cuDoubleComplex*)malloc(n / 2 * sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
se2 = (cuDoubleComplex*)malloc(n / 2 * sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
for (int a = 0; a<n / 2; a++)
{
    se[a].x = data[2 * a];
    se[a].y = data[2 * a + 1];
    se2[a].x = data2[2 * a];
    se2[a].y = data2[2 * a + 1];
}
limitenu = round(((B / 2) * 60000) / fsi);
lnu = 2 * limitenu + 1;

result = (cuDoubleComplex**)malloc(ltau1 * sizeof(cuDoubleComplex*));
for (int k = 0; k < ltau1; k++)
{
    result[k] = (cuDoubleComplex*)malloc(lnu * sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
}

result = mainfft(se, se2, fsi, ltau1, ret_max, B);
}
```

---

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cufft.h>
#include <cufftXt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuComplex.h>
#define BATCH 1


cuDoubleComplex** mainfft(cuDoubleComplex *se, cuDoubleComplex *se2, int fsi, int ltau1, double ret_max, int B)
{
    cufftHandle plan;
    double Ts, *tau;
    int lse, ltau, lnu, limitenu, n;
    int aux = -ltau1;
    int aux2 = 2 * ltau1 + 1;
    cuDoubleComplex *temp, *temp2, *res_fft, **x;
    //double *device_array; //a lo mejor no es necesario, o si eso para los datos de la fft

Ts = 1 / fsi; //Periodo de muestreo

              //Creacion eje de desplazamientos temporales
lse = sizeof(se) / sizeof(cuDoubleComplex);                 //Longitud de la señal
tau = (double*)malloc(aux2 * sizeof(double));               //Reserva en Host
                                                            //cudaMalloc((void**)&device_array, aux2 * sizeof(double)); //Reserva en GPU        //cudaFree al final para liberar memoria de los malloc
for (int ind = 0; ind < aux2; ind++)
{
    tau[ind] = aux*(ret_max) / ltau1;
    aux++;
}
ltau = sizeof(tau) / sizeof(double);

//Creacion eje de desplazamientos frecuenciales
limitenu = round(((B / 2)*lse) / fsi);
lnu = 2 * limitenu + 1;

//
//Generacion de la matriz
//
x = (cuDoubleComplex**)calloc(ltau1, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex*));
for (int k = 0; k < ltau1; k++)
{
    x[k] = (cuDoubleComplex*)calloc(lnu, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
}

cufftPlan1d(&plan, lse, CUFFT_C2C, BATCH);

for (int i = 0; i < ltau; i++)
{
    n = round(tau[i] / Ts);

    if (abs(n) < lse)
    {
        if (n >= 0)
        {
            temp = (cuDoubleComplex*)calloc(lse, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
            temp2 = (cuDoubleComplex*)calloc(lse, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
            for (int j = 0; j < (lse - n); j++)     //SE2 TIENE OTROS INDICES, CORREGIIIIIR, QUIZAS NI SIQUIERA HAGA FALTA FOR
            {
                //ComplexMUL <<< 32, 256 >> >(se, se2, temp); 
                temp[j].x = (cuCreal(se[j])*cuCreal(cuConj(se2[j + n]))) + cuCimag(se[j])*cuCimag(cuConj(se2[j + n]));
                temp[j].y = (cuCreal(se[j])*cuCimag(cuConj(se2[j + n]))) + cuCimag(se[j])*cuCreal(cuConj(se2[j + n]));
                //cudaMemcpy(device_array, temp, aux2 * sizeof(cuDoubleComplex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);       // copia de datos de Host a GPU
                //cudaMemcpy(lse2, &lse, aux2 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                cufftXtExec(plan, temp, temp, CUFFT_FORWARD);
                cudaDeviceSynchronize();
                cufftDestroy(plan);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            temp = (cuDoubleComplex*)calloc(lse, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
            for (int l = -n; l < lse; l++)
            {
                //ComplexMUL <<< 32, 256 >> >(se, se2, temp);
                temp[l].x = (cuCreal(se[l])*cuCreal(cuConj(se2[l + n]))) + cuCimag(se[l])*cuCimag(cuConj(se2[l + n]));
                temp[l].y = (cuCreal(se[l])*cuCimag(cuConj(se2[l + n]))) + cuCimag(se[l])*cuCreal(cuConj(se2[l + n]));
                cufftXtExec(plan, temp, temp, CUFFT_FORWARD);
                cudaDeviceSynchronize();
                cufftDestroy(plan);
            }
        }
        res_fft = (cuDoubleComplex*)malloc((limitenu + 1) * sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
        for (int m = 0; m < (limitenu + 1); m++)
        {
            res_fft[m] = temp2[m];
        }
        for (int n = 0; n < limitenu; n++)
        {
            x[i][limitenu + n] = res_fft[n];
        }
        int u = limitenu - 1;
        for (int o = 0; o < limitenu; o++)
        {
            x[ltau - i][o] = res_fft[u];
            u--; //para el flipr
        }
    }
}
return(x);
}
```

El error me salta en la linea 8 del primer código, nada mas acceder al main, si pudierais ayudarme os estaría eternamente agradecidos.

> **PD:** Sé que mi programación es nefasta, no es el tema del hilo pero si se os ocurriera algún fallo que cometo o forma de mejorarla bastante evidente también lo agradecería.

> **PD2:** No se si esto ayudará pero utilizo Visual Studio 2015 update 3 con el *toolkit CUDA 8.0 de Nvidia*.

Comment: No tengo experiencia con CUDA, lo único que me llama la atención es que declares una función externa `extern cuDoubleComplex** mainfft(cuDoubleComplex *se, cuDoubleComplex *se2, int fsi, int ltau1, double ret_max, int B);` dentro del cuerpo del `Main()`. No debiera estar afuera de cualquier función?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Al parecer es un comportamiento normal de C, [mirar esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895981/c-function-declaration-within-another-function)

Comment: @NaCl, gracias, la verdad desconocía.